# How to re-render directive after a variable is changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a directive for star rating. But the template the is loaded before data is loaded from HTTP. So i want to reload directive template after HTTP request is successful.

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head><body>


<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="movieCtrl">

<div star-rating rating="starRating" read-only="false" max-rating="10" click="click(param)" mouse-hover="mouseHover(param)"
        mouse-leave="mouseLeave(param)"></div>
        </div></body></html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller("movieCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.starRating = 0;
  $scope.hoverRating = 0;


  $scope.mouseHover = function(param) {
    $scope.hoverRating1 = param;
  };

  $scope.mouseLeave = function(param) {

    $scope.hoverRating1 = param + '*';
  };
  //problem here
  //actual data coming via http
  //when value is changed i want to re-render below directive template
  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.starRating = 5
  }, 1000);
});
app.directive('starRating', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      rating: '=',
      maxRating: '@',
      readOnly: '@',
      click: "&",
      mouseHover: "&",
      mouseLeave: "&"
    },
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: "<div style='display: inline-block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor:pointer;' ng-repeat='idx in maxRatings track by $index'> \
                    <img ng-src='{{((hoverValue + _rating) <= $index) && \"http://www.codeproject.com/script/ratings/images/star-empty-lg.png\" || \"http://www.codeproject.com/script/ratings/images/star-fill-lg.png\"}}' \
                    ng-Click='isolatedClick($index + 1)' \
                    ng-mouseenter='isolatedMouseHover($index + 1)' \
                    ng-mouseleave='isolatedMouseLeave($index + 1)'></img> \
            </div>",
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      if (!attrs.maxRating || (Number(attrs.maxRating) <= 0)) {
        attrs.maxRating = '5';
      };
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.maxRatings = [];

      for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.maxRating; i++) {
        $scope.maxRatings.push({});
      };

      $scope._rating = $scope.rating;

      $scope.isolatedClick = function(param) {
        if ($scope.readOnly == 'true') return;

        $scope.rating = $scope._rating = param;
        $scope.hoverValue = 0;
        $scope.click({
          param: param
        });
      };

      $scope.isolatedMouseHover = function(param) {
        if ($scope.readOnly == 'true') return;

        $scope._rating = 0;
        $scope.hoverValue = param;
        $scope.mouseHover({
          param: param
        });
      };

      $scope.isolatedMouseLeave = function(param) {
        if ($scope.readOnly == 'true') return;

        $scope._rating = $scope.rating;
        $scope.hoverValue = 0;
        $scope.mouseLeave({
          param: param
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

See [Codepen](http://codepen.io/akmittal/pen/vLXYEv) for more info.

Comment: With directives, the controller is shared across all instances of the directive, making your code incorrect (unless everything has the same rating). You should tie the template to the scope.rating so that you get the benefit of the template updating when your rating changes

Comment: @SoluableNonagon The directive is using an isolate scope, so $scope is different for each instance of the directive's controller. Though in this case there is nothing being done in the directive's controller that can't be done in the linking function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple rating directive which uses stars, note that the logic is in the `link` function, rather than the controller.

```
function starRating() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template:
      '<ul class="star-rating" ng-class="{readonly: readonly}">' +
         // see ng-repeat here? this will update when scope.stars is updated
      '  <li ng-repeat="star in stars" class="star" ng-class="{filled: star.filled}" ng-click="toggle($index)">' +
      '    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>' + // or &#9733
      '  </li>' +
      '</ul>',
    scope: {
      ratingValue: '=ngModel',
      max: '=?', // optional (default is 5)
      onRatingSelect: '&?', // callback
      readonly: '=?' // set whether this should be changeable or not
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      if (scope.max == undefined) {
        scope.max = 5;
      }
      function updateStars() { // update to rating value
        scope.stars = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
          scope.stars.push({
            filled: i < scope.ratingValue
          });
        }
      };
      scope.toggle = function(index) {
        if (scope.readonly == undefined || scope.readonly === false){
          scope.ratingValue = index + 1;
          scope.onRatingSelect({
            rating: index + 1
          });
        }
      };
      scope.$watch('ratingValue', function(oldValue, newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
          updateStars();
        }
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. Instead of re-rendering the directive when a variable changes, you use `ng-repeat` to re-render the DOM when the variable changes.

Comment: If you have only 1 item you can ng-repeat like this: `ng-repeat="myobject in [myobject]"` and get the same re-rendering effect

Answer (score 3):

Use $scope.$apply() on `setTimeout` function and your code will work fine

also i have made simple modification to your code .. [check here](http://codepen.io/basilin/pen/PZGoQq?editors=101)

- i created a service to share data b/n controllers
- added some $watch function to detect value change

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller("movieCtrl", function($scope, $http, share) {

  $scope.starRating = 0;
  $scope.hoverRating = 0;

  $scope.mouseHover = function(param) {
    $scope.hoverRating1 = param;
  };

  $scope.mouseLeave = function(param) {
    $scope.hoverRating1 = param + '*';
  };
  $scope.$watch('starRating', function() {
    share.rating = $scope.starRating
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('timeout set');
    $scope.starRating = 5;
    $scope.$apply();
  }, 1000);
});
app.factory('share', function() {
  var obj = {
    rating: 0
  }
  return obj;
});
app.directive('starRating', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      rating: '=',
      maxRating: '@',
      readOnly: '@',
      click: "&",
      mouseHover: "&",
      mouseLeave: "&"
    },
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: "star1.html",
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      if (!attrs.maxRating || (Number(attrs.maxRating) <= 0)) {
        attrs.maxRating = '5';
      };
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, share) {
      $scope.maxRatings = [];
      $scope.rating = share.rating;
      $scope.$watch('rating', function() {
        $scope._rating = share.rating;
      });
      for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.maxRating; i++) {
        $scope.maxRatings.push({});
      };

      $scope._rating = share.rating;

      $scope.isolatedClick = function(param) {
        if ($scope.readOnly == 'true') return;

        $scope.rating = $scope._rating = param;
        $scope.hoverValue = 0;
        $scope.click({
          param: param
        });
      };

      $scope.isolatedMouseHover = function(param) {
        if ($scope.readOnly == 'true') return;

        $scope._rating = 0;
        $scope.hoverValue = param;
        $scope.mouseHover({
          param: param
        });
      };

      $scope.isolatedMouseLeave = function(param) {
        if ($scope.readOnly == 'true') return;

        $scope._rating = $scope.rating;
        $scope.hoverValue = 0;
        $scope.mouseLeave({
          param: param
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```